# Typescript definition with custom const enum

Tags: typescript, commonjs, typescript-typings

I'm trying to create TypeScript definition files for a library.

The library has a method that accepts a parameter of type `number`, but that parameter can only be a certain set of numbers, so I want to have my definition say it requires an enum type that I created using a `const enum`.

However, when I define my class in a `.d.ts`, like so:

```
// definitions/SimpleDefinition.d.ts

/// <reference path="Enums.ts" />

declare class SampleDefinedClass {
    public static SampleMethod(enumArg: Enums.SampleEnum): void;
}
```

My enum like this:

```
// definitions/Enums.ts

export const enum SampleEnum {
    Item1 = 1,
    Item2 = 2
}
```

And I have an `index.d.ts` to tie the 2 together:

```
// definitions/index.d.ts

/// <reference path="Enums.ts" />
/// <reference path="SampleDefinition.d.ts" />
```

The compiler tells me this:

```
../definitions/SampleDefinition.d.ts(4,41): error TS2503: Cannot find namespace 'Enums'.
```

I have tried adding an import to the top of my `SampleDefinition.d.ts`, but that resulted in the definition not being properly recognized in my code file. Though Visual Studio and Visual Studio code won't show an error on the actual import.

`import Enums = require("./Enums");`

```
Main.ts(6,1): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'SampleDefinedClass'.
```

I have tried several more thing, like using AMD, and moving files around, but can't seem to get this to work. Is there a way to do this? Or will I have to find another way to do it/give up?

I've created a [GitHub repo](https://github.com/Rene-Sackers/TypeScriptDefinitionsTest) with this exact sample.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `SampleDefinition.d.ts` does not have top-level import or export, and `Enum.ts` does. That is, `Enums` is a module, while `SampleDefinition` is not, but you are trying to use `Enums` in it. Using older (outdated) terminology, `SampleDefinition.d.ts` is an internal module, and `Enums` is external module, and you can't mix the two in one application.

There are two ways to make them consistent:

**One way** is to make everything internal, without any import/export at top level:

fixed `Enum.ts`: wrap `export` in a `namespace`

```
namespace Enums {
    export const enum SampleEnum {
        Item1 = 1,
        Item2 = 2
    }
}
```

fixed `Main.ts` - just remove `import Enums ..` line

```
/// <reference path="../definitions/index.d.ts" />

console.log(Enums.SampleEnum.Item2);
SampleDefinedClass.SampleMethod(Enums.SampleEnum.Item1);
```

**Another way** is to turn everything into a module:

fixed `SampleDefinition.ts` : use `import` instead of `reference`, and `export` class instead of declaring it:

```
import Enums = require("./Enums");


export class SampleDefinedClass {
    public static SampleMethod(enumArg: Enums.SampleEnum): void;
}
```

fixed `Main.ts`: again, `import` everything explicitly instead of `reference`. That way, you don't need `definitions/index.d.ts` at all:

```
import Enums = require("../definitions/Enums");
import {SampleDefinedClass} from "../definitions/SampleDefinition"


console.log(Enums.SampleEnum.Item2);
SampleDefinedClass.SampleMethod(Enums.SampleEnum.Item1);
```

Which way to choose is up to you. The main difference is that with modules, your app will require module loader at runtime. Without modules, it can be compiled into one combined script file. This matters mostly for browsers (where you have to provide module loader yourself), modular code compiled for node will use `require` and will work just fine.

Comment: I have applied your first suggestion to a new branch: https://github.com/Rene-Sackers/TypeScriptDefinitionsTest/tree/edit-1 but I'm still getting `Cannot find name 'SampleDefinedClass'`

Comment: That's because you have `export class SampleDefinedClass` in `SampleDefinition.d.ts` in that branch. Original code has `declare class SapmleDefinedClass`, which should work with the first option.

Answer (score 0):

On a definition file you have to export enums with `declare`.

I looked up some examples from [DefinitelyTyped](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=enum), here is one:

```
export declare enum EDeflateStrategy {
    DEFAULT_STRATEGY = 0,
    FILTERED = 1,
    HUFFMAN_ONLY = 2,
    RLE = 3,
    FIXED = 4,
}
```

The problem with your code is that your definition file seems to be looking at a .ts file instead of another .d.ts file.

If this is your library and it is written in ts you can just add

```
"declaration": true
```

on your tsconfig.json file and let tsc generate the definition for you.

If it is not you can try to mock things from this library in ts and let the tsc generate declarations for you by enabling this option.

Comment: I'm afraid I can't use that, because I need my enum to compile. The original method accepts a number argument, and a const enum will compile to the actual numeric value in .js